# Unable to import module 'index': cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' in AWS lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, python-imaging-library, aws-lambda-layers

My lambda function uses library pillow for image conversion. It works fine locally. However, when I deploy it to AWS - I get

> Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'index': cannot
> import name '_imaging' from 'PIL'

I am using lambda layer Klayers-p38-Pillow by ARN. I have verified and confirmed that python version matches the layer runtime version (3.8) and that the architecture is x86_64.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?